# How to create certificate .cer file?

Tags: iis-7, ssl, certificate

I would like to work with certificates and the third part authority send me values:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]Many letters and digits[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[...]Many letters and digits[...]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But I need a .cer file to put in my IIS. How can I create this .cer file?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you've been given is a Certificate (the public part, signed by a trusted party) and the associated key (the private part). In simple terms it's the private key that allows your app to sign stuff in a way that the remote party can then validate using the public part, the certificate. Your server needs to have both linked together so that protocols like SSL\TLS can work properly.

In your case you have been given a complete pair, not just the Cert. The format you have been given it is called PEM and unfortunately Windows Certificate Manager can't import that natively (to the best of my knowledge).

The quickest way I've found to convert it is to install [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) somewhere and convert the file you have to PKCS#12 format using the following command. You will need to break the file you got from the CA into two parts, one containing the certificate block called "certificate.txt" and and one containing the private key block called "key.txt":

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycertkey.p12 -in certificate.txt -inkey key.txt
```

Once you have the PKCS#12 format file you can import it into Windows:

- Open the MMC ( Start -> Run ->
  MMC.exe ) and then select add\remove
  snap-in and add in the Certificates
  snap in.
- Select "Computer Account" as the
  context.
- Right click the "Personal" folder and
  select the "Tasks>Import"
- Find the mycertkey.p12 file you
  created and import the certificate
  and private key into the Computer's
  Certificate store.

Once the cert is installed you can now assign it from within IIS (this may vary a bit depending on IIS version)

- Open you IIS Management Console and
  right click the domain you want to assign
  the certificate to.
- Select Properties
- Select the "Directory Security" tab, and
  then "Server Certificates"
- Follow the Certificates Wizard
  prompts, selecting Next, then
  select "Assign Certificate" and then Next again.
- Find and select the certificate you
  have just imported and click OK.

That should do it.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, but openssl tells me : Loading 'screen' into random state - done
unable to load private key

Comment: and now, I have a "no certificate matches private key"

Comment: Possibly something got corrupt while splitting the PEM format file. If you try the Openssl command using the original file from your CA as both the -in file and -inkey file it should work too. If it can match the pair it will prompt you for a password for the p12 output file.

Comment: should be that, I've re-exported the file, and it's ok.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: In your openssl command, changing the output filename from mycertkey.p12 to mycertkey.pfx will allow easier import.  PFX is a registered file extension in Windows that you can just double click on to start the certificate import wizard.

Comment: @Ryan - I'm pretty sure that will result in the cert\key pair going into the user's cert store - I've always preferred to put certs where I know they belong.

Comment: @Helvick Now that you mention it, I think you're right.

Comment: @Helvick - For the sake of breaking file into two, how do you recognize how much part is private key block and how much part is certificate block?

Comment: In a PEM format file you should be able to use BEGIN CERTIFICATE/BEGIN CERTIFICATE and BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY/END RSA PRIVATE KEY to decide but it will be safer to use something like OpenSSL to import the source file and then export the cert(s) and keys separately, that way you get some confidence that they are valid.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-setup-ssl-on-iis-70/) covers the process of creating a certificate request and installing the certificate once the signing authority (GoDaddy, Thawte, etc.) has issued your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The string you pasted is Base64 DER encoded X.509 certificate.

What certificate file format does IIS expect?
The simplest try is to save this stuff in a .cer file and pass it to IIS.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions for details